# ECS task dynamic port mapping and docker communication

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I have a `TaskDefinition` that defines 2 docker images, and these 2 docker images needs to communicate between each other.

The first docker container, let's call it `Frontend`, calls the second docker container, `Backend`, using its name and **port**. Which means, inside the Frontend container there is a call to the Backend container using `container_name:container_port`.

Using dynamic port mapping does not allow me to do that, because I can't find the exposed port of the Backend container. An idea would be to find it with some script and then pass it to the Frontend container, but that seems very hacky.

Using static port mapping, I can achieve that. However, if one of the ECS task fail, a new one will be spun-up and it is very likely that this new task will fail to run, because it will be placed on an EC2 instance where the port are still exposed (so, it will fail to bind the docker port to the host).

Kind of the same issue is described [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3778) as well.

What could be the way to achieve such configuration?

Comment: Is there a reason why you have to access the container on the same host?

Comment: Yes unfortunately, it's a requirement.

Comment: If you're worried is there anyway you can set essential to true on that particular container definition, within your task definition. More details here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_environment. Seems like a safer way to guarantee the frontend won't break if your backend breaks.

Comment: Agreed, but that does not solve the underlying issue :s

Comment: In that case if you want to use a Dynamic port, but must use the container locally on the same host you will need to perform a script. Dynamic Ports are generally used when a container is forwarded traffic from a Load Balancer.

Comment: I use both, so the ALB redirect to different ports which are mapped to different containers. But the containers needs to also communicate with themselves using port ... Well, I guess I'll script stuff...